# How to mark / cursor inside of curly braces when opening set of curly braces

Tags: auto-complete-mode, js2-mode, electric-pair-mode

I am using `js2-mode` as well as `electric-pair-mode` and `autocomplete`.

When I create a function using `function () {` and press `enter` the second curly brace is made on the next line but my cursor is placed on the same line, right next to it.  I wind up with something that looks like:

```
function test () {
*}
```

Where my cursor is where the `*` is.  I am used to behavior that would leave it like this:

```
function test () {
   *<-cursor here
}
```

Is there a way to re-enable that?